# using .join method in python removes first and last items in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the string representation of my class correct.
To do this I need to concatenate several lists into a string.
The lists should be whitespace separated in the string.

These are my lists:

```
[['C', 'A'], ['C', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['C', '4'], ['C', '5'], ['C', '6'], ['C', '7'], ['C', '8'], ['C', '9'], ['C', 'T'], ['C', 'J'], ['C', 'Q'], ['C', 'K'], ['S', 'A'], ['S', '2'], ['S', '3'], ['S', '4'], ['S', '5'], ['S', '6'], ['S', '7'], ['S', '8'], ['S', '9'], ['S', 'T'], ['S', 'J'], ['S', 'Q'], ['S', 'K'], ['H', 'A'], ['H', '2'], ['H', '3'], ['H', '4'], ['H', '5'], ['H', '6'], ['H', '7'], ['H', '8'], ['H', '9'], ['H', 'T'], ['H', 'J'], ['H', 'Q'], ['H', 'K'], ['D', 'A'], ['D', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['D', '4'], ['D', '5'], ['D', '6'], ['D', '7'], ['D', '8'], ['D', '9'], ['D', 'T'], ['D', 'J'], ['D', 'Q'], ['D', 'K']]
```

This is the code I use to join them:

```
    def __str__(self):
    str_deck_cards = 'Deck contains '
    for t in self.deck_cards:
        str_deck_cards += ' '.join(t)
    return str_deck_cards
```

However my output looks like this:

```
Deck contains C AC 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C TC JC QC KS AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S TS JS QS KH AH 2H 3H 4H 5H 6H 7H 8H 9H TH JH QH KD AD 2D 3D 4D 5D 6D 7D 8D 9D TD JD QD K
```

Why is it not joining the lists correctly?

I've also tried with set()

```
    def __str__(self):
    str_deck_cards = 'Deck contains '
    for t in self.deck_cards:
        str_deck_cards += ' '.join(set(t))
    return str_deck_cards
```

But it still doesn't get it right.
I'm out of ideas now, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: `' '.join(t)` will take each list (in the loop) and join them together with a space between them. so `['C', 'A']` would result in `C A` which is what you get. You do that for each element. You really want to use `''.join(t)` to join the sublist and then add a `' '` (space) between each with something like `str_deck_cards += ''.join(t) + ' '` or you could replace the entire loop with `str_deck_cards = ' '.join([''.join(x) for x in list])`

Comment: If you need the cards to be shown as a value/suit instead of suit/value then you may have to reverse the strings that get joined with something like `str_deck_cards = ' '.join([''.join(x[::-1]) for x in list])` which results in this string `'AC 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C TC JC QC KC AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S TS JS QS KS AH 2H 3H 4H 5H 6H 7H 8H 9H TH JH QH KH AD 2D 3D 4D 5D 6D 7D 8D 9D TD JD QD KD'`

Comment: Where I used `list` just replace it with `self.deck_cards` in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually nothing is removed. You are placing a space between two characters in a sublist `C AC 2` not between two sublists `CA C2`. So replace :

```
str_deck_cards += ' '.join(set(t)) # gives C AC 2C 3C 4C 5...
```

by:

```
str_deck_cards +=''.join(t)+' ' # gives CA C2 C3 C4 C5...
```

This will fix the issue.

Comment: I don't mean to brag :) but I think my answer fits best (after the edit) because it already takes care of the last whitespace that will be added to the string for no reason in the method provided here. Also, I believe it's more pythonic.

Comment: @GabrielAmram I think my comments provided the most complete answer which also considered the more natural way of displaying cards in a deck and is more like the OPs original output too ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The `.join` takes an iterable and adds the string you wanted BETWEEN the items. So this works as expected.

What you want is that when concatenating the strings generated, a whitespace is added so -

`str_deck_cards += ' '.join(t) + ' '`

of course, at the end, if necessary, you'll have to get rid of the trailing whitespace.

**== Edit ==**

you could also do something like that:

`return 'Deck contains ' + ' '.join([' '.join(x) for x in self.deck_cards])`

Comment: `return 'Deck contains ' + ' '.join([''.join(t) for t in self.deck_cards]` (with the empty string on the join in the list comprehension?

Comment: well that depends on the wanted output.. i thought spaces were needed everywhere...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is also what I was looking for. I didn't actually consider a list comprehension for this